# Twilio phone verificarion API custom name and message

Tags: twilio, verification

I'm using Twilio to verify users phones, and I've noticed that the SMS users receive have a weird sender name 'AUTHMSG' and the wording uses my app slug which is 'my-cool-first-application'. And I don't know how to fix that. I wasn't aware that my user-unfriendly slug will appear in the SMS. I can see there's `customFriendlyName` parameter in the new version of SDK, but I get the error `Custom friendly name not allowed` which is weird. How do I change my slug (not the project name, because that's not the case)? Is there a way I can get a custom name and custom message text in verification SMS? Would it help to create a new project for the new slug? Can I transfer the money between projects?

Answer (score 1):

I found a console with all listed verification services and that's where you can change it
https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/services

Comment: To save others time: You can edit the friendly name for the verification service on that page in the console, but you can't enable the ability to customize friendly names on a per verification basis there. See below answer, its a paid feature.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a paid feature: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/customization-options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Vonage](https://www.vonage.com/) API,you can send free custome code for upto 32 request(depends on country you living)....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const sendOTP = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body + "this is req.body");

  const phone = '+91' + req.body.phone;

  client.verify.v2.services
    .create({ friendlyName: 'Your custom name' })
    .then(service => console.log(service.sid))
    .then(() => {
      // After service creation, send verification code
      client.verify.v2.services(verifySid)
        .verifications.create({ to: phone, channel: "sms" })
        .then((verification) => console.log(verification.status))
        .then(() => {
          // Your additional code here
        });
    });
};
```

You can change in trial mode in my provided Node.JS code replace the `'Your custom name'` with your custom name and after will get custom OTP name and go [here](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/services) and you can find your custom SID and copy and paste it in your code.